# How to convert JSON value to string in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have a json object like this:
`{path: "images/125/17062017/home.jpg"}`.It's coming from rest api. 
I want to get this path `'images/125/17062017/home.jpg'`. And I need
to store that path in string variable. I tried like this.
`JSON.parse(response).path`, `response.path`. But these ways are not working.

```
 fileChange(event: any) {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
     let file: File = fileList[0];
     this.fileUploadService.saveOwnImageFile(file)
      .subscribe( (response: any) =>{
          console.log(response);   // response = {path:'images/125/17062017/home.jpg'}
          let value = JSON.parse(response);  // getting error here
          console.log(value);
      });
     }
}
```

Comment: response.json()?

Comment: why's that ? couldnt just write `let value = response.path` ?

Comment: not working. i tried that ways

Comment: what is the problem ? could you provide a plnker please ?

Comment: @SathishKotha did my solution worked or need more help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you would like to get the value `'images/125/17062017/home.jpg'`, you should use `let value = response.path;`.

`JSON.stringify(response)` would return the string `{ "path" : "images/125/17062017/home.jpg" }`.

Comment: I have cache in my project.I cleaned it. now response.path is working,thanks robbannn

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to upvote if you found this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify()
JSON.stringify()
Use `JSON.stringify(..);`

```
fileChange(event: any) {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
     let file: File = fileList[0];
     this.fileUploadService.saveOwnImageFile(file)
      .subscribe( (response: any) =>{
          console.log(response);   // response = {path:'images/125/17062017/home.jpg'} 
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          let value = response.json().path.toString();
     ///// note your object is response
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          console.log(value);
      });
     }
}
```